# Will remapping ; break my plugins?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

If I map Vim 's native shortcut & key codes (e.g. `nn ; :`) do other plugins break (e.g. break on their commands & command line)?

*Actually I saw `nn ; :` on an article but the writer of the article said that it may break some plugins. Why It may break some plugins?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all depends on the plugins you use:

When the author says that mapping `;` to `:` may break a plugin, they simply mean that you won't be able to use `;` anymore and if a plugin has a command which uses the `;` the command might not work anymore.

Now this mapping is pretty common on qwerty keyboards so it shouldn't be a problem on most plugins.

Your best bet is to use this mapping and see if you encounter a plugin which uses `;`. If that is the case you can either stop using the plugin (or try to replace it) or remap another key to `;` (e.g. `nnoremap : ;`) and use `:` instead of `;`.

Note that in vanilla vim `;` is used to repeat the last `t`, `T`, `f` or `F` command.

*On a totally different topic, don't use `nn` use `nnoremap` instead it is much easier to read and considered as a best practice*

Comment: In short, if `nnoremap ; <nop>` breaks some plugin, then it is bug in that plugin, not in your setting.